# bits and arrays in C - New to programming

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I have a given code from school, I need this as my output:
Digital Binair
0   is    000,
1  is   001,
2  is     010,
3  is     011,
4  is     100,
5  is    101,
6 is    110,
7  is    111
 (3 bits)

```
 I need to work with for loops, this is the given code:



#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ZERO '0'
#define ONE '1'

int main(void) 
{
    char rij[8][4];
    int n, m;

    strcpy( rij[0], "000" );
    printf( "%s\n", rij[0] );

    for ( n=1; n<8; n++ ) 
    {
        strcpy( rij[n], rij[n-1] );
        printf( "%s\n", rij[n] );

        // *ONLY ABLE TO TYPE IN HERE !!!! THE REST IS GIVEN !!!!*
    }

    for( n=0; n<8; n++ ) 
    {
        printf( "%i %s\n", n, rij[n] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm stuck at is how do I make a for loop that is working with bits. So lets say `for(n = 0; n < 8; n++)` how do I make the loop go form `000` to `001` to `010`.

Comment: Is the question "solve my homework"?

Comment: Yes, well I actually need help with it. you dont have to give me answers but maybe some hints.

Comment: But you haven't asked anything. What are you stuck at?

Comment: Well, that is my bad. Sorry!  The thing im stuck at is how do  I make a for loop thats working with bits. so lets say 
   for(n = 0; n < 8; n++)
how do  I make the loop go form 000 to 001 to 010. Sorry English isnt my main language

Comment: Notice that the last character is alternating every `n`. The second one is alternating every two `n`s. The first one - every four `n`s...

Comment: So I need to make 3 loops? one for the first bit, one for the second and one for the third?

Comment: No, you can use the modulus operator `%` - think what it will give for `n % 2`, `n % 4` and such. There are other methods - you can work with bits of `n` directly by shifting (`<<`, `>>`) and masking. But it is too broad for the question.

Comment: Oh ofcourse, I could work with the modulos, But what have the arrays to do with it, since  you can get the same output without the arrays right? for example   if(n % 4 == 0){ printf ("1"} else printf "0"

Comment: @EugeneSh. : the question is more interesting than that.  You have to do it within the constraints of the given code and the indicated insertion point.  It serves no purpose other than to make you think, and demonstrate in this case an understanding of the binary increment operation at the bit-level.

Comment: Is that really how the code was provided - it is much easier to see what is going on if you use consistent and conventional indentation.  Fixed it for you.

Answer (score 0):

While there are many ways of generating a binary sequence, here the task appears to have been deliberately complicated (or made interesting) by the constraint that you modify code only at the location indicated and the initialisation of each successive string with the content of the previous one.

The arrays serve no purpose other than to make you think - it is a purely academic exercise, not a practical application.  Each string is initialised with the content of the previous string (which the code you must add will have modified), the intent of the exercise is that you perform a binary "add 1" at each iteration.

To do that, starting from the LSB (`rij[n][2]`), if the digit is `ZERO` you set it to ONE, then move to the next `n`, else you set it to ZERO, and "carry" one, repeating the above process for the next most significant bit in the string `n`.

You can do that in a loop from the LSB (2) index to the MSB (0) index, and exiting the loop (`break`) when you set any bit to `ONE`.

Or for just three digits you can unroll-the loop thus:

```
if( rij[n][2] == ZERO )
{
    rij[n][2] = ONE ;
}
else
{
    rij[n][2] = ZERO ;
    if( ...  // test next bit [1] - enough of a hint I think.
```